# QImage to Numpy Array using PySide

Tags: python, qt, numpy, pyqt, pyside

I am currently switching from PyQt to PySide.

With PyQt I converted `QImage` to a `Numpy.Array` using this code that I found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406149/pyqt-pyside-how-do-i-convert-qimage-into-opencvs-mat-format):

```
def convertQImageToMat(incomingImage):
    '''  Converts a QImage into an opencv MAT format  '''

    incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(4)

    width = incomingImage.width()
    height = incomingImage.height()

    ptr = incomingImage.bits()
    ptr.setsize(incomingImage.byteCount())
    arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)  #  Copies the data
    return arr
```

However `ptr.setsize(incomingImage.byteCount())` does not work with PySide as this is part of the [`void*` support](http://pythonxy.googlecode.com/hg-history/4ef4255f59b092a123a5788c821434d9fe94aee9/src/python/PyQt4/PLATLIB/PyQt4/doc/html/gotchas.html#support-for-void) of PyQt.

My Question is: How can I convert a QImage to a `Numpy.Array` using PySide.

**EDIT:**

```
Version Info
> Windows 7 (64Bit)
> Python 2.7
> PySide Version 1.2.1
> Qt Version 4.8.5
```

Comment: PySide doesn't seem to offer a `bits` method. Is this also part of PyQt? How about using [`constBits`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.constBits)?

Comment: m( can´t believe I didn´t see that! Thanks a lot. If you repost your comment as a Answer I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Done, but is that adequate to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, as it was the only thing missing to get it working. I edit my Question to add the working code in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySide doesn't seem to offer a `bits` method. How about using [constBits](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.constBits) to get the pointer to the array?

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution with `constBits()` did not work, but the following worked:

```
def QImageToCvMat(incomingImage):
    '''  Converts a QImage into an opencv MAT format  '''

    incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGBA8888)

    width = incomingImage.width()
    height = incomingImage.height()

    ptr = incomingImage.bits()
    ptr.setsize(height * width * 4)
    arr = np.frombuffer(ptr, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
    return arr
```

Comment: Be aware that using `bits()` instead of `constBits()` creates a deep copy. This may or may not be what you intend.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I need the deep copy because I want to manipulate the data. At least I get an access violation if I do not use `bits()`

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use `QImage.constBits()` as suggested by @Henry Gomersall. The code I use now is:

```
def QImageToCvMat(self,incomingImage):
    '''  Converts a QImage into an opencv MAT format  '''

    incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGB32)

    width = incomingImage.width()
    height = incomingImage.height()

    ptr = incomingImage.constBits()
    arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)  #  Copies the data
    return arr
```

Comment: Wonderful!Do you know the inverse of it ?

Comment: @Maham That would best be asked in a seperate question

Comment: @Silencer: You may want to ask that as a question showing us what exactly is not working. I am using PyQt5 and it is working for me.

Comment: Sorry about this. I find the reason: I display  using `cv2.imshow` and `QLabel` at the same, then they confllict for some reason of `gtkXXX`. But when I comment off the `cv2.imshow`, it works. Sorry again.