# How do I change each pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, pyqt, qimage

I am new to Python and I still don't know what exactly Qimage's pixel returns (it seems to a tupel of rgb or rgba -the lack of type declaration doesn't help) 
I want to grab each each pixel and change it.

```
newqim = QImage(imWidth, imHeight, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
for xstep in range(0, imWidth - 1):
    for ystep in range(0, imHeight - 1):

        pixelValueTuple = im.getpixel((xstep, ystep))
        pixelR = pixelValueTuple[0]
        pixelG = pixelValueTuple[1]
        pixelB = pixelValueTuple[2]
        copiedValue = qRgb(pixelR, pixelG, pixelB)

        newqim.setPixel(xstep, ystep, copiedValue)
```

Above is the provided code ,I thought I then iterate over that newqim, but I can't get a handle on how exactly I would do that in Python.

```
for xstep in range(0, imWidth-1):
    for ystep in range(0, imHeight -1):
```

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/q/18406149/566035, people convert it to either numpy array or opencv mat. But opencv python binding (cv2) plays very well with numpy now so most people would use just numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you want, but since you are new to Python, here go a few tips...

### Unpacking

This code:

```
pixelR = pixelR[0]
pixelG = pixelValueTuple[1]
pixelB = pixelValueTuple[2]
```

Is the same as:

```
pixelR, pixelG, pixelB = pixelValueTuple[:3]
```

If you are sure `len(pixelValueTuple) == 3`, then it is just:

```
pixelR, pixelG, pixelB = pixelValueTuple
```

### PEP-8

A bit of nitpick, but python guys tend to be a little nazy about syntax. Please read PEP-8. From now on I'm naming variables according to it (`camelCase` for instance variables just hurt my eyes %-).

### Range

You probably want `range(width)` instead of `range(0, width-1)`.

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> range(0, 10 - 1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

### Now back to your problem.

```
width, height = 300, 300
im = QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)

for x in range(im.width()):
    for y in range(im.height()):
        r, g, b, a = QColor(im.pixel(x ,y)).getRgb()
        # ... do something to r, g, b, a ...
        im.setPixel(x, y, QColor(r, g, b, a).rgb())
```

### Example

```
width, height = 100, 100
im = QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_ARGB32)

for x in range(im.width()):
    for y in range(im.height()):
        im.setPixel(x, y, QColor(255, x * 2.56, y * 2.56, 255).rgb())

im.save('sample.png')
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, as I said I have no clue about Python syntax/semantics , so I am not sure what the range(0, width-1) is doing. I assumed it was the starting point for the iteration like a Java "for loop" I got that code stub as a starting point, I have to write image manipulation functions like multiply, add, gamma, etc.

Comment: You probably want something like `im = QImage(); im.load('sample.png')` then. BTW, the QColor class has a lot of useful methods, check the docs.

Comment: Thank you Paulo you've been very helpful .the image is indeed loaded further up in the code, just need to better understand how to manipulate each single one of them

Comment: You are welcome. Just to be clear, do you consider your question answered? If so, you can signal this by clicking the green checkmark on the left - and if not, how can I improve my answer in order to get it accepted?